# How to do math on a read column in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble adding a number to a column.
For instance if I have a code that gives an output:

```
    ['1', '2', '3', '7']
    ['4', '5', '6', '8']
    ['9', '6', '3', '9']
```

I want to add three to the first column so it becomes 4,7,12. I would like to do similar math on the second column.  So far all I can do is read in the first column using `line.split`.

```
with open("data.txt","r") as inData:
    for line in inData:
        line=line.strip()
        x,y,z=line.split("\t",2)
        print(x)
```

This is the code I have so far.  It prints the first column.

Comment: Can you provide your code so far so that we can help you to fix it?

Comment: Columns? What are you using, CSV?

Comment: A clue: You are reading character data, and you can only add numerical values. Make sure you convert the data to numbers before you do any math.

Comment: You need to put 4 spaces in front of each line of code for it to display properly

Answer (score 1):

First you read the text

```
In [1]: with open('data.txt', 'r') as df:
    txt = df.read()
   ...:     

In [2]: txt
Out[2]: '1 7 12\n2 8 13\n3 9 14\n'
```

Then you break it up and convert it to numbers;

```
In [3]: items = txt.split()

In [4]: items
Out[4]: ['1', '7', '12', '2', '8', '13', '3', '9', '14']

In [8]: items = [float(n) for n in items]

In [9]: items
Out[9]: [1.0, 7.0, 12.0, 2.0, 8.0, 13.0, 3.0, 9.0, 14.0]
```

Using slicing, you can now get the individual columns:

```
In [10]: items[0::3]
Out[10]: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

To which you can then add a number using a list comprehension:

```
In [13]: new1 = [j+3 for j in items[0::3]]

In [14]: new1
Out[14]: [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]

In [15]: new2 = [j-3 for j in items[1::3]]

In [16]: new3 = [j*2 for j in items[2::3]]

In [21]: new2
Out[21]: [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]

In [22]: new3
Out[22]: [24.0, 26.0, 28.0]
```

You can then convert the new colums into rows;

```
In [23]: zip(new1, new2, new3)
Out[23]: [(4.0, 4.0, 24.0), (5.0, 5.0, 26.0), (6.0, 6.0, 28.0)]
```

The rows you can write to a file.

Comment: You asked how to add to first and second column.  I provided how to add 3 to each column in every row.  Can you be more specific

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to have some kind of table in your file. One way of dealing with tables in python is by creating a list of lists:

```
table = []
```

`table` is going to be our table. It is declared as an empty list.

Now, we need to read your file. Let's assume it is called 'input.txt':

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    # Now we can use your command
    x, y, z = line.split('\t', 2)
    table.append([x, y, z])
```

After this point you have in `table[i]`, for i going from 0 to the number of lines in your file, containing each of the lines. `table[i][j]` is the j-th element in the i-th line, with j, in your case, going from 0 to 2.

Now, you can add 3 to each number in the table with:

```
 for i in range(0,len(table)):
     for j in range(0,3):
         table[i][j] = table[i][j] + 3
```

Comment: I keep getting an error 'int' object is not iterable for the line: for  i in len(table).  Is it because my actual data ranges from small decimals to whole numbers with decimals?

Answer (score 0):

```
#This should print each line.

with open("data.txt","r") as inData:
  for line in inData:
    line=line.strip() 
    line_list = line.split("\t",2)
    print(line_list)

    # now add 3 to each and print again
    for n in line_list:
      new_n = float(n) + 3
      print new_n,
    print
```

Comment: It added 3 for a row of numbers.  How can I make it add 3 to a column of numbers?

Comment: run the code.  It adds 3 to each column in each row

Comment: when I did, it added 3 to only the last row of numbers.  I think it sees each row as an array instead of each column so it only adds 3 to the last row

Comment: you are wrong I think.  I left several print statements in to see what was going on.

Comment: ok I'll check again.  Will it still work for the data I edited above?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right. your data.txt file includes something like that:

```
1 2 3   2 4 6   3 6 9
2 4 6   4 8 12  6 12 18
3 6 9   6 12 18 9 18 27
```

and you want get something like that:

```
4 5 6   5 7 9   6 9 12
5 7 9   7 11 15 9 15 21
6 9 12  9 15 21 12 21 30
```

I created something which almost solved it, then i found Roland Smith solution very useful , actually he answered this perfectly (except the writing) imho. So i used his style and made this:

```
def do_math():
    with open("data.txt", "r") as df:
        txt = df.read()
        items = txt.split()
        items = [int(n) for n in items]
        data = zip([i+3 for i in items[::3]], 
                   [i+3 for i in items[1::3]], 
                    [i+3 for i in items[2::3]])

    with open("data_new.txt", "w") as df:
        for i in range(len(data)):
            for j in range(len(data[i])):
               df.write(str(data[i][j]))
               if j < 2:
                   df.write(" ")
            df.write("\t")
            # new line
            if (i+1)%3==0:
                df.write("\n")
```

Hope it's useful, even if its not perfect.